# Django Shows Page Source Instead Of My Webpage

Tags: python, django, django-views

I have found that when passing context and a title into my views it causes the page to only show its html source code instead of the actual frontend graphics. If i remove the title being passed in then it works again but i do want to have the title passed in so is there any way to have this work?

Views

```
def myPosts(request):

    context = {
        'products': Post.objects.all()
    }

    return render(request, 'create/my_posts.html', context, {'title_page': 'My Posts'})

class PostListView(ListView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'my_posts.html'
    context_object_name = 'products'
```

Comment: Please post your files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you are passing context yo can do something like this
context = {
'products': Post.objects.all(),
'title_page': 'My Posts'
}
and finally pass
return render(request, 'create/my_posts.html', context)

In the front end, you can use it as context.title_page